# How to change the date format in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting Response from Webservices Date like "2012-08-17T00:00:00". I want to Display Date only like 17-08-2012. How Change Date format and Remove that time...

Comment: Read up more on NSDateFormatter

Comment: `NSDateFormatter*dFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];dFormat.dateFormat=@"dd-MM-yyyy";` , do what @Bourne suggested.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//String froms web service(ws) 

NSString *stringFromWS =[NSString stringWithString:@"2012-08-17T00:00:00"];


//date formatter for the above string
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterWS = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterWS setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date =[dateFormatterWS dateFromString:stringFromWS];


//date formatter that you want 

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterNew = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterNew setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSString *stringForNewDate = [dateFormatterNew stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Date %@",stringForNewDate);
```

also refer the link for more explanation 
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-2.html

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Date today: %@", today);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
dateFormat.dateFormat =  @"dd-MM-yyyy";
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);
```

Also see the below date and time format styles

> ```
> NSDateFormatterNoStyle
> NSDateFormatterShortStyle
> NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
> NSDateFormatterLongStyle
> NSDateFormatterFullStyle
> ```

You can set it like  `[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];`