# How to Change Date and Time Format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the date format in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984285/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-iphone-sdk)

Actually I'm getting a string in 24 Hours time format.  I want to display 12 hours time format.

Here's my input :

```
2012-10-19T04:10:00

2012-10-06T14:00:00
```

I would like to have the following format :

```
10-19-2012 4:10 AM

10-06-2012 2:00 PM
```

Comment: see my answer for default short time output and also get all info about dateformatter from my blog http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

:use the NSDateFormatter to change the date

Here Your input:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *Yourcurrenttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Yourstring];
```

And date converted to the String ..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterNew = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterNew setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *stringForNewDate = [dateFormatterNew stringFromDate:Yourcurrenttime];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDateFormatter` with format type `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a`.
Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you’d just need to use the default styles defined in `NSDateFormatterStyle`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

[dateFormatter release];
```

// Output: Dec 2, 2008 3:58 PM

also you can get output from coding with DateFormatter like bellow..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyy HH:mm:s a"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"]; //You can set different formats for the date
NSLog(@"Current Date %@",[formatter getStringFromDate:currentDate"]);
[formatter release];
```